# Usage of preposition

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

"White considered the manner **in** **which** a culture adapts to it's environment to be the most significant factor in it's development."
Now my question is the sentence idiomatic?Here **which** is a relative pronoun. Can i write the sentence in this way.
"White considered the manner which the culture adapts **in to** it's environment to be the most significant factor in it's development".
If i can write then how 'adapts in to it's environment' then if  'in' is preposition and if it does , then what is it's object?

I have seen it on BBC english Learning English | BBC World Service

Comment: No, you can't. They mean different things.

Comment: As @User40475 says, you can't. And you want the possessive "its", not the contraction "it's" twice in your quoted sentence.

Comment: Is this sentence idiomatic? No. Idioms are short phrases and occasionally short sentences, not long, convoluted sentences like this.